# Javascript: Get word selection in anchor tags

Tags: javascript

I'm currently writing a add-on for chrome. 
I want to get word selection by using a hot key + mouseclick. With normal text, I can do it by using window.getSelection() like below

```
    var s = window.getSelection();
s.modify('extend','backward','word');        
var firstPart = s.toString();

s.modify('extend','forward','word');
var lastPart = s.toString();
s.modify('move','forward','character');
var txt = firstPart + lastPart;
```

However It doesn't work if I try it with words in a links. It doesn't work. If there any way or javascript library I can use to do it.

Please help me!

Comment: What happens when you try it on `<a>` tags?

Comment: Here is the log data I got when tried to do it with anchor tag.

Selection {type: "None", extentOffset: 0, extentNode: null, baseOffset: 0, baseNode: null…}
anchorNode: null
anchorOffset: 0
baseNode: null
baseOffset: 0
extentNode: null
extentOffset: 0
focusNode: null
focusOffset: 0
isCollapsed: true
rangeCount: 0
type: "None"
__proto__: Selection

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you are using an onclick event. I'm still not 100% certain what behavior you expect, but I did notice an interesting difference between using `onclick` and `onmouseup`. I've put a demo into a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EGmV3/1.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <p>Hold down 'F9' then select this text...</p>
    <p><a href="#">Now try it with this text..</a></p>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var hotKeyIsDown = false;

window.onkeydown = function(ev) {
    hotKeyIsDown = false;
    if(ev.which === 120) //F9 key
        hotKeyIsDown = true;
}

window.onkeyup = function(ev) {
    hotKeyIsDown = false;
}

// try changing this to `window.onclick'
window.onmouseup = function (){
    if(hotKeyIsDown) {
        var s = window.getSelection();
        s.modify('extend','backward','word');        
        var firstPart = s.toString();

        s.modify('extend','forward','word');
        var lastPart = s.toString();
        s.modify('move','forward','character');

        var txt = firstPart + lastPart;
        alert("You were selecting '" + txt + "'");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying me. 
I tried with your code. While I was holding F9, I clicked at a word in links, then It didn't give me the exact word I clicked on. It gave me wrong word. But when I click at space under words, and It worked fine. I wonder how I can capture the exact work that I click on ?

Comment: It seems that the browser doesn't move the selection if the user clicks on an anchor tag. This might be some inconsistency in the spec or whatever. To work around this, I used the range object that's available inside of the click event to create a new selection (`ev.rangeParent`, `ev.rangeOffset`). A demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/EGmV3/3/. Does this resolve the problem you were facing?